# Post-hoc test in the context of cluster analysis

Tags: clustering, post-hoc

I performed a cluster analysis based on a principal components. Total sample size is around 140. Now I want to describe the differences among the clusters (by means of the components) while performing a post-hoc analysis. By using the Levene test, I found out that the homogeneity of the variances can be assumed. I have the following questions:

1) Can I assume normal distribution for the ANOVA, since the components are z-transformed?

2) Which post-hoc test is appropriate? I have unequal simple size considering the clusters. I might go for Tukey-Kramer test.

Comment: The clusters are _in vitro_ made groups maximized ("overfitted") to differ. They usually cannot be seen as if random samples of natural classes. Classic statistical testing  (their p-values) therefore is useless. However, you may use effect sizes of tests to find out which variables discriminate which clusters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! So I can describe my clusters along  the original variables by using ANOVA (although the cluster analysis was performed on the basis of pca)?

Comment: You can (and ought to) describe them on any variables at your hand. But _testing_ if they differ significantly on any variable _which_ participated in clustering (be it the PCs or the original variables which gave those PCs) is useless.

Comment: So there is no way to describe how the clusters differentiate from each other?

Comment: Once again: You can and may check how _greatly_ any clusters differ on this or that variable. What you should not do is to conclude if that difference is statistically _significant_ - when you test on _those_ variables that participated in clusterization. Why? See the 1st comment.

Comment: I still have one question: which post-hoc test is the most appropriate in my case? Tukey or Scheffe? Thanks!